# How to remove Powered by Drupal?

Tags: 7

I just installed Drupal 7.2 on my localhost using xampp, made some pages, and installed a theme, I'm also modifying the CSS of the theme to my own convenience.

My front page has (at the end of the content, not the footer) a "Powered by Drupal" written over there. In WordPress I would just edit the content PHP file, and delete that; with Drupal, I can't find where the line is located.

I thought the index.php would give me some ideas, but I think Drupal works differently.

How exactly do I find my front page in the directories? I have a c:\xampp\htdocs\drupal7 main directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal constructs the pages you see using blocks and nodes through a template file. To find that text, look in menu option "website information", next if not found look in the block list for a block placed in copyright or footer area.

Drupal will depend on block/regions; learn that too. Finally, when that doesn't work, in /sites/all/themes/ you'll find the PHP and HTML files delivering the themed page.

Comment: Ok I got it, you were right, the line "Powered by drupal" was in fact a block, after finding the block management menu I disabled that block from showing, thanks. It still makes me wonder, where are the blocks installed? like If I wanted to show "Powered by John!!" rather than the original, where should I go?

Comment: @user2091756 – You'd create your own blocks then. Just see the docs :)